# Why does my list print out every other element?

Tags: python, list

So, I want to design a small file that contains all the functions of the cards of a larger card game, but when I return the hand that it pulls the cards from it shows every other card, rather than the top `x`

```
hand = []
cards = [(list of all the cards, it is long)]

def draw(deck, num):
    print("You draw %s cards from the top of the deck.") % (str(num))
    for x in range(num):
        drawn_cards = deck.pop(x)
        add_cards = hand.append(drawn_cards)
    return drawn_cards
    return add_cards
```

When I print out the hand after shuffling the deck, say I call the function like         `draw(cards, 5)` it's supposed to remove the top 5 cards and then append them to the hand, but it appends 5 every other card

For example the deck is shuffled and the top 10 look like this:

```
Ace of Diamonds,
Ace of Hearts,
Seven of Hearts,
Eight of Hearts,
Ten of Hearts,
King of Diamonds,
Nine of Diamonds,
Three of Hearts,
Four of Diamonds,
Two of Spades
```

When I print my hand it looks like this:

```
['Ace of Diamonds', 'Seven of Hearts', 'Ten of Hearts', 'Nine of Diamonds']
```

Which that is 5 every other card, I need the top 5 cards. Why does it do this?

Comment: Why are you passing `x` to `deck.pop()`? Do you understand what the argument means?

Comment: in addition to pop also reconsider your return statement(s)

Answer (score 1):

`pop(x)` not only returns the  element at index x in the list but it also removes it from the list.

A better way would be:

```
def draw(deck, num):
    print("You draw %s cards from the top of the deck.") % (str(num))
    hand = []
    count = 0
    while count < num:
        card = deck.pop(0) #always take the top card off the deck
        hand.append(card)
    return hand
```

Note that this removes elements from your deck list every time.  Also, every time you call draw, a new hand is created.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you take away from the list while incrementing your index. You `pop` the irst element, so the formerly second element becomes first and formerly third one becomes second, then you increment the loop variable and pop the second element, which is now the originally third one. This skips the originally second element, and so forth.

Either just access the elements:

```
drawn_card = deck[x]
```

or modify it but always `pop` the first element.

Another way to access the first five elements at once:

```
hand = deck[:5]
```

Also, there's no point in handling the return value of `list.append()`; it'll always be `None`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because within your loop you use deck.pop(x). This will start by popping the 0th element, then the 2nd element, then the 4th element, etc. Because you remove an element each time this will only give you every second card. Additionally, this code will break if you try to pop more than half of the size of the deck.

You just need to replace deck.pop(x) with deck.pop() and this code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

add cards is null because append return None.  Try something like this in python:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.append(4)
b = a.append(4)
```

b will be equal to none.  Also you have two return statements in a row.  Your second return statement will never occur.

Lastly, to explain the skipping dynamic.  You are popping your deck as you draw.  Try a smaller experiment:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for x in xrange(2):
    print(lst.pop(x))
```

as you pop the 0th element, the lst becomes:

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

so lst.pop(1) will pop the 3 instead of the two!  This is why it is not a good idea to iterate on a lst that you are impacting with each action.